# Cascading delete across multiple tables in android/sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to cascade deletes so that when I delete a record from `myFooTable` all the associated records in `myFooBarLinkTable` and `myBarTable` are deleted as well.  A simplified version of my current DB schema attempt is below.  When I delete a record from `myFooTable` the associated records in `myFooBarTable` are deleted; but the records in `myBarTable` are still present.

```
public class MyDatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE myFooTable (fooID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "fooText1 TEXT," +
                "fooText2 TEXT " +    
                ");");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE myBarTable (barID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "barText1 TEXT, " +
                "barText2 TEXT);" );

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE myFooBarLinkTable (fooBarLinkID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "fooLinkID REFERENCES myFooTable(fooID) ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
                "barLinkID REFERENCES myBarTable(barID) ON DELETE CASCADE);" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON DELETE CASCADE` [works only one way](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions); these clauses in the `myFooBarLinkTable` table definition trigger only when a record in the *referenced* table is deleted, i.e., in either `myFooTable` or `myBarTable`.

If you want the deletion to happen in the other way, you have to write your own trigger, or execute separate `DELETE` commands from your app.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer using either triggers or manual deletes?

Comment: No; whatever works best for you. (You'll have to write `DELETE` commands either way.)